# Chromedriver fails inside WSL after updating Windows to 1903

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, selenium, windows-10-v1903

I run Chromedriver as a Windows executable from inside WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux) to run automated tests. The reason for this is that Chrome itself is installed in Windows.

However after updating to Windows 1903, this has stopped working. Chromedriver always returns error code 1, even when invoked as `chromedriver --version`.

When executed outside WSL, `chromedriver --version` correctly returns the version information.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Filed https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4088

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be due to Chromedriver being started via a symlink.

Removing the .exe extension in Windows and making sure the Windows folder was on the PATH solved the issue.

This seems like a WSL regression in 1903.

Comment: Yes, this indeed was a Windows regression in 1903 and Microsoft is working on a fix.